# EOM Variable using sysfunc?

Tags: sas

I have the below code which gets the first day of the month in YYYYMMDD format. But I need to adjust to End of Month.

```
%let CLNA_EOM = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&sysfunc(date()),-1),yymmddn8.);
```

I tried adding ,'E' after the -1 but that doesn't work.

```
%let CLNA_EOM =%sysfunc(intnx(month,&sysfunc(date()),-1,'E'),yymmddn8.);
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the macro processor everything is a string, so there is no need to add quotes around literal strings.

The INTNX() function does not understand the value 'E' that you gave it. Use either E or END.  Just like you used MONTH instead of 'MONTH' when telling INTNX() what type of interval to use.

```
%let CLNA_EOM =%sysfunc(intnx(month,&sysfunc(date()),-1,E),yymmddn8.)
```